# If the Cell value is blank then copy the cell value from another 2 cells using concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the below VB Code but its not working, In the excel file
if Column BS = Blank then Take the Value from Column T and O, combine with _(underscore) and populate it in Column BS, If Column BS is not blank then no action required.

Similarly if Column BT =Blank then Take the Value from Column T and O, combine with _(underscore) and populate it in Column BT, If Column BT is not blank then no action required.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows

  If rw.Columns("BS") = "" And rw.Columns("BT") = "" Then

    rw.Columns("BS") = rw.Columns("T") & " _" & rw.Columns("O")

    rw.Columns("BT") = rw.Columns("T") & " _" & rw.Columns("O")
  End If

Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Run time error 424, Object required

Comment: I think you need to clarify what sheets usedrange you are using, is this the line that errors?

Comment: After compiling i get this error, in My file i have around 500 rows and 65 columns. Can you pls advise what could be the error else, what should be the code for the above condition

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: line 2 For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows

Comment: try activesheet.usedrange.rows

Comment: Get the error Next without for- Compile error

Comment: What should be correct be the correct code for above condition?

Comment: Can someone help me to answer this query